# Actionbar Sherlock moves while typing

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, actionbarsherlock

In my Layout-XML, there are five EditText and I am using Actionbar Sherlock.
When I am typing in the fifth EditText and the keyboard appears, 
the whole Layout moves upwards, even the Actionbar.
Why does it behave like this and what can I do, to make the Actionbar static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way in my experience was put a vertical scroll view in layout which contains all your Edit Text

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with different `android:windowSoftInputMode` settings in your manifest for that particular activity.  It sounds like you want `adjustResize` or `adjustNothing`.  See the documentation here (toward the bottom) for more information about the windowSoftInputMode options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html